# Would it be possible for a disk controller to load an OS by itself?

Tags: hard-drive

For some obvious reasons what i'm asking would i'm sure be an inefficient way of doing things but i just wanted to ask some experts in the hardware/software field if it would be possible..

My scenario would be that the on board firmware of the HDD/SSD controller would set a predefined amount of time in its own timer before starting a DMA transfer to host memory. The firmware would already be pre programmed with the address/count of where to DMA into ram by programming the controllers registers.

Back to the timer bit...This predefined amount of time before it started to DMA to host memory is the amount of time the cpu takes to fetch the Bios/Uefi from its Nor flash or whatever and initialises all other hardware including the SSD/HDD and then once it had done all that was programmed to raise a halt so the cpu would stop using the bus. The SSD/HDD would then interrupt the cpu once it had loaded the OS.

I know this probably sounds a mad question to ask but i like to really dig down to a low level to see how things work and wonder if you could do this or if someone can explain to me that this wouldn't be possible for some reason or wouldn't make sense?

Sorry if this isn't the correct forum to ask such a question

Answer (score 0):

## Yes -- okay, *no*.

The necessary work [has been done](http://spritesmods.com/?art=hddhack). It turns out that disk controllers have more than enough spare memory and CPU to do this sort of tricks - *the rootkit of your nightmares*.

So the **effect** you want **can** be obtained by the hard disk supplying to the CPU an OS different from the real one (if any, even).

But it cannot be done *by the hard disk taking control*. It doesn't work that way.

Comment: Thanks for the reply and i've read that article before. Might you say my way of doing it is possible though?

Comment: *"but it has been done"* -- No, you exaggerate. Hacking a HDD is not the same as the OP's question.

Answer (score 0):

> Would it be possible for a disk controller to load an OS by itself?

No, not with the typical PC architecture.
The integrated controller of a HDD/SSD can only communicate with the host computer through the SATA interface.
The SATA interface has a master/slave hierarchy: the host computer is the master, and the HDD/SDD is the slave device.
IOW the what and when of a data transfer is under the control of the host computer, not the HDD/SSD.

Regardless of how the drive was hacked, the host computer still has control.
E.G. DMA/host-bus transfers and SATA operations (which are two different operations that you seem to conflate) still have to be initiated by the host computer, and the HDD/SDD has no capability of initiating a DMA/host-bus transfer or a SATA operation.

Most of what you write makes no sense.

Comment: Thanks for the reply SawDust, I sort of already knew that and should of put that in my question. I guess stupidly what I'm asking is could you design the controller to do it which is of course yes but that would be fundamentally re-designing how a host works with all peripherals. Does the host also have to setup pcie routing of the SATA interface so even if you designed an SSD controller with more intelligence it wouldn't know where to send data anyway? That's if I'm right in thinking DMA\SATA traffic has to go through PCIE?

Comment: You're trying to get the tail to wag the dog.  This site is not for discussions or hypothetical computers.  PCIe is arbitrated at the HW level; the CPU (i.e. software) doesn't have to be involved.